# How to use the ExecuteReaderAsync method from NReco DbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, nreco, executereader

I'm trying to convert some code that uses NReco.Data to async version of ExecuteReader (ExecuteReaderAsync) but the methods requires many parameters. Any ideas ?

https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.Data/html/M_NReco_Data_DbDataAdapter_SelectQuery_ExecuteReaderAsync__1.htm

This is the working code with no-async version of ExecuteReader is:

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = nreco_DbDataAdapter.Select(sql_query).ExecuteReader(
                        (rdr) =>
                        {
                            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                            ds.Tables.Add(new NReco.Data.DataReaderResult(rdr).ToDataTable());
                            rdr.NextResult();
                            ds.Tables.Add(new NReco.Data.DataReaderResult(rdr).ToDataTable());
                            return ds;
                        }
                        );
```

Not sure what paremeters I need to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact usage of `ExecuteReaderAsync` is pretty the same as `ExecuteReader` and the only difference is that 'read' handler should be async -- something like that:

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = await nreco_DbDataAdapter.Select(sql_query).ExecuteReaderAsync(
    async (rdr, cancel) => {
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(await (new NReco.Data.DataReaderResult(rdr)).ToDataTableAsync(cancel));
        rdr.NextResult();
        ds.Tables.Add(await (new NReco.Data.DataReaderResult(rdr)).ToDataTableAsync(cancel));
        return ds;
    }, cancellationToken
);
```

This code should be in async method. If you don't have 'cancellationToken' here you can specify `CancellationToken.None`.